# Wrong button outputs. Ps4 to Esp32

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, ps4

So, I am trying to build a quadruped robot with some servos and an Esp32 development board. All the hardware must be controlled with a PS4 contoller. But there is something wrong with Esp32 to Ps4 connection. For example When i press L2 button the program says "R2 button pressed".

Here is the test code i upload.

> ```
>  #include <PS4Controller.h>
>     void setup() {
>   Serial.begin(115200);
>   PS4.begin("03:03:03:03:03:03");
>   Serial.println("Ready.");
> }
>
> void loop() {
>   // Below has all accessible outputs from the controller
>   if (PS4.isConnected()) {
>     if (PS4.Right()) Serial.println("Right Button");
>     if (PS4.Down()) Serial.println("Down Button");
>     if (PS4.Up()) Serial.println("Up Button");
>     if (PS4.Left()) Serial.println("Left Button");
>
>     if (PS4.Square()) Serial.println("Square Button");
>     if (PS4.Cross()) Serial.println("Cross Button");
>     if (PS4.Circle()) Serial.println("Circle Button");
>     if (PS4.Triangle()) Serial.println("Triangle Button");
>
>     if (PS4.UpRight()) Serial.println("Up Right");
>     if (PS4.DownRight()) Serial.println("Down Right");
>     if (PS4.UpLeft()) Serial.println("Up Left");
>     if (PS4.DownLeft()) Serial.println("Down Left");
>
>     if (PS4.L1()) Serial.println("L1 Button");
>     if (PS4.R1()) Serial.println("R1 Button");
>
>     if (PS4.Share()) Serial.println("Share Button");
>     if (PS4.Options()) Serial.println("Options Button");
>     if (PS4.L3()) Serial.println("L3 Button");
>     if (PS4.R3()) Serial.println("R3 Button");
>
>     if (PS4.PSButton()) Serial.println("PS Button");
>     if (PS4.Touchpad()) Serial.println("Touch Pad Button");
>
>     if (PS4.L2()) {
>       Serial.printf("L2 button at %d\n", PS4.L2Value());
>     }
>     if (PS4.R2()) {
>       Serial.printf("R2 button at %d\n", PS4.R2Value());
>     }
>
>     if (PS4.LStickX()) {
>       Serial.printf("Left Stick x at %d\n", PS4.LStickX());
>     }
>     if (PS4.LStickY()) {
>       Serial.printf("Left Stick y at %d\n", PS4.LStickY());
>     }
>     if (PS4.RStickX()) {
>       Serial.printf("Right Stick x at %d\n", PS4.RStickX());
>     }
>     if (PS4.RStickY()) {
>       Serial.printf("Right Stick y at %d\n", PS4.RStickY());
>     }
>
>     if (PS4.Charging()) Serial.println("The controller is charging");
>     if (PS4.Audio()) Serial.println("The controller has headphones attached");
>     if (PS4.Mic()) Serial.println("The controller has a mic attached");
>
>     Serial.printf("Battery Level : %d\n", PS4.Battery());
>
>     Serial.println();
>     // This delay is to make the output more human readable
>     // Remove it when you're not trying to see the output
>     delay(1000);
> ```

[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1wVo.png)

Comment: either you're confusing left with right or that's a bug. either in your hardware or in that library, given that lines come as an example with the library. I guess you should contact the developers of that library

Comment: i was using non-original controller. That was the problem...